# Calculating Average Lifetime Value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to determine the average lifetime value of a customer for all customers and also a second query to determine the same thing for a period of the last 30days.

I have a customers table (tblcustomer) containing:

customerID
customername

I also have a service table (tblservice) containing:

serviceID
date       with format:(mm/dd/yyyy)
price

Here query I have thus far for calculating the average of the total:

```
SELECT Sum(tblservice.Total) AS Totals
FROM tblservice;
```

Here query I have thus far for calculating the average of the last 30day total:

```
SELECT Sum(tblservice.Total) AS Totals
FROM tblservice
WHERE ((tblservice.Timing)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date()));
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone would be able to help me out with how to calculate the average for each of these queries. I have little to no SQL experience.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer as this seems to solve my problem:

```
SELECT AVG(tblservice.Total) AS OrderAverage FROM tblservice;

SELECT AVG(tblservice.Total) AS OrderAverage FROM tblservice
WHERE ((tblservice.Timing)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT AVG((tblservice.Total) AS average FROM tblservice;

SELECT AVG(tblservice.Total) AS OrderAverage FROM tblservice
WHERE ((tblservice.Timing)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date()));
```